# Find area between $3$ functions

Tags: calculus, area

Find the area between the curve $y=4-x^2$, the tangent line of the parabola at $x=1$ and the vertical asymptote of $f(x)=x\ln{(x-3)}$.

---

The tangent line of the parabola at $x=1$ is $$y=-2x+5.$$ The V.A. of $f$ is $$x=3,$$ so I think the area to look for is

[image: Area]

So I did $$\int_1^3{\left[(-2x+5)-\left(4-x^2\right)\right]}\;\text dx=\cdots=\boxed{\frac 83},$$ nevertheless [WolframAlpha says other thing ($\frac{16}3$)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+4-x%5E2+and+-2x%2B5+and+x%3D3).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your work is correct

Comment: You forgot the restriction $x = 1$ in WA

Comment: compare the bounds of integration in your link to WolframAlpha compared to what you have here on this page

Comment: @AndrewLi how can I add that? I tried adding "... and $x=1$" but it gave me error.

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate yeah I know, but why why does that happen?

Comment: @manooooh http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+4-x%5E2+and+-2x%2B5+from+x+%3D+1+to+x+%3D+3

Comment: area between y=4-x^2 and y=-2x+5 and x=3 and x=1 
is ok.

Comment: Sorry @AndrewLi, the answer of W. mu is better because you are supposing you know the bounds integration.

Comment: @manooooh He is too?

Comment: @AndrewLi Oh, I thought $x=1$ was "the tangent line of the parabola at $x=1$", I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram sets the left border itself by solving the equation. For example:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The left border: $5-2x=3 \ \text{or} \ 4-x^2=3 \Rightarrow x=1 \ \text{or} \ x=\pm 1 \Rightarrow x=-1.$

Another example:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The left border: $5-2x=4 \ \text{or} \ 4-x^2=4 \Rightarrow x=\frac12 \ \text{or} \ x=0 \Rightarrow x=0.$

Conclusion: Show the left and right borders to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Following your link I see that W-A shows:

$\int_{-1}^1 (1 - 2 x + x^2) dx + \int_1^3 (1 - 2 x + x^2) dx = 16/3≈5.33333$

But I don't see why it wants to calculate over the interval [-1,1].

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. It's crazy!!

Comment: Nonetheless, you have the correct region, integration and answer.  This is why we haven't been replaced by machines... yet.

Comment: $x = -1$ is a root of $x^2 -2x+1$. WA may have treated it as a point of intersection thus a lower bound.